# Subdomain rewrite rules for file access not to effect main site files

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have set up virtual subdomain. and i want to make htaccess to achive the following flow

For 
www.domain.com

it should call the index file but for the subdomain

```
abc.domain.com
```

The rewrite rule should be like

```
RewriteRule www.domain.com/index.php?var=abc
```

i mean it should (in HTACCESS) pass the subdomain to the index file as an argument

and for the Other file requests like

```
abc.domain.com/file.php
```

The subdomain should be rewritten like `www.domain.com/file.php?var=abc`

I mean the Rewrite rule like

```
RewriteRule www.domain.com/file.php?var=abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com/index.php?subdomain=%1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&subdomain=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be how you could do them on an individual basis.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com/file.php?var=abc [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^def\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com/file.php?var=def [L]
```

Comment: No The subdomains are dynamic and i need a general rule that whenever a subdomain calls a file then that file should be called with the VAR= SUBDOMAIN arguments so that the file can process for the subdomain... i can not have hardcoded rules...